# Hyper-V VM on Windows 8 - No Network Access

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have a VM set up in Hyper-V and 2 virtual switches that SHOULD allow me to RDP to the VM and for the VM to have access to the internet. I can RDP to the VM, but the VM does NOT have access to the internet. I have it configured as follows. Can anyone see my problem? I thought I had this setup working before:

**Hyper-V Switches:**

[image: Internal Switch]
[image: External Switch]

**VM Adapter Settings**
[image: VM Adapter Settings - Internal]
[image: VM Adapter Settings - External]

**Host Adapter Settings**
[image: Host - Internal Switch Adapter Config]
[image: Host - External Switch Adapter Config]

**Guest Adapter Settings**
[image: Guest - Internal Switch Adapter Config]
[image: Guest - External Switch Adapter Config]

Comment: Does the guest VM external NIC have a valid ip address and default gateway? Is the guest VM running DNS server software?

Comment: The Guest VM is running Server 2008R2 and is a Domain Controller. The last image in the list is the Guest External Adapter, and it gets its address automatically. Is there a test I should to do see if it's getting a valid IP?

Comment: 1. It's not recommended that a DC/DNS server have a DHCP asigned ip address. 2. You can run ipconfig/all from a command prompt on the DC to see if it has a valid ip address and default gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My setup is working now ... I think I had to reboot or something before the settings started to take hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just started working. I think these settings are OK, but there was something else going on that made it so my VM couldn't connect to the internet. After a few days (and several restarts) I checked again, everything was working.

Comment: Clicked through hoping to find an answer to the very same problem, but this is not an answer at all. "it started working on its own" is at best reason to delete the question because there is no problem anymore. Without a solution, this just gets people's hopes up =(

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hi, you can reask without problem. Just link there for a background. The answer itself doesnt answer futur readers directly, but it give hints and does stop the question to be bumped and let it know that hes no longer needing help, so it’s useful :)

Comment: It doesn't give hints at all: it just says "the problem went away on its own". That's not useful to anyone, not even the original poster: no one gained, or can gain, insight from this.